# New line in h:ouputtext for title

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I write,

```
<h:outputText title="Hello&#013;World"
              style="color: red; white-space: pre-line;"
              escape="false" rendered="#{!empty details.faults}"
              value="Faults" />
```

it works fine but when I write,

```
<h:outputText title="#{details.faults}"
              style="color: red; white-space: pre-line;"
              escape="false"
              rendered="#{!empty details.faults}"
              value="Faults" />
```

in database faults = `Hello&#013;World`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unescape the *faults* to get the same effect as when you're using directly the literal. Your best bet is to do it in a backend bean, using e.g. [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)

```
public String getFaults() {
    return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(faults);
}
```

just note that if your using the *faults* for places other than title,  the safer would be to have a dedicated *getTitle* method and do the unescaping within that method